# Order by with conditions

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Try to get this in following order but doesn't work, it does not return the right order, where Cancelled is picked before Unpaid, please let me know

```
       dt = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .OrderBy(x => x["TicketStatus"].ToString())
            .ThenBy(x => x["TicketStatus"].ToString() == "Attended")
            .ThenBy(x => x["TicketStatus"].ToString() == "Issued")
            .ThenBy(x => x["TicketStatus"].ToString() == "Unpaid")
            .ThenBy(x => x["TicketStatus"].ToString() == "Cancelled")
            .GroupBy(x => new {EventID = x["EventID"].ToString(), ContactID = x["ContactID"].ToString()})
            .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? At a guess, you need to write a custom `IComparer<string>` and pass it as the second argument to `.OrderBy()`

Comment: what do you means with "doesnt' work" ? What happens and what did you expect ?

Comment: == will compare the object references, which will never be equal. Try using a .Equals() instead, e.g. x["TicketStatus"].ToString().Equals("Attended")

Comment: @N0ug4t But strings are interned...

Comment: @N0ug4t that doesnt work, ive found the solution thanks guys

Comment: It's not returning the right order but I found the solution thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just find out this works

```
        List<string> sortOrder = new List<string> { "Attended", "Issued", "Unpaid", "Cancelled" };

        dt = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .OrderBy(x => sortOrder.IndexOf(x["TicketStatus"].ToString()))
            .GroupBy(x => new {EventID = x["EventID"].ToString(), ContactID = x["ContactID"].ToString()})
            .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
string[] status= { "Attended", "Issued", "Unpaid", "Cancelled" };

var sortstatus = from s in status
                  orderby s
                  select s;
```